# Can we remove tag and title edits from "recent activity"?

Tags: feature-request

Generally speaking, tag-soup cleanup is beneficial and encouraged, right? Well, one *downside* to such effort is that questions that undergo such cleanup are considered *recently active* by the system, and appear on the WPSE front page as such.

Is there any way to *exclude* tag edits from being considered as a question "update", or otherwise exclude mere tag edits from recent activity?

#### Edit

And title edits, too

Comment: and title edits too...

Comment: Why? Isn't an improved question worth a second look? If it isn't – the question is so bad that it wasn't worth an edit.

Comment: Tag/title edits can be used to improve *usability* and *searchability* of WPSE, without regard to the quality of the question itself or the quality of posted answers.

Answer (score 2):

The start page shows by default the *active* questions. An edit is an activity. Sometimes an edit makes a question answerable or it makes tag subscribers aware of it.

Some edits need a review – even when the editor has the privilege to [edit immediately](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). Making edits *silent* opens the door to misuse this privilege.

We have a separate [view for the newest questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) that doesn't take edits into account.

What *is* difficult: mass editing. When someone edits a lot of old questions new questions move down on the front-page and that's not fair against those who asked recently.
I see two solutions:

- Do not edit more than four old question in a row.
- Edit when we have low activity: between 0.00 and 5.00 UTC or on weekends.

Both are rather workarounds. But I don't see a better compromise.